# Float position in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I want to set a position of my element to the right within a `div` element. `float:right`  doesn't work, so I try `margin-left:auto`, but it looks beautiful if I have a single element only. How can I achieve that for multiple elements?

My CSS:

```
  .toolbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #1976d2;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
  }

  .toolbar a {
     /*float:right;*/
    margin-left: auto;
  }
```

Comment: Please, provide your code.

Comment: `float` is a css property and has nothing to do with `angular`, so please provide your code, so we can help you figure out where did you go wrong

Comment: Sorry, I have added my code.

Comment: `What does Angular replace "float" with?` - Are you refering to [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) which *emulates the behavior of shadow DOM by preprocessing (and renaming) the CSS code to effectively scope the CSS to the component's view*

Comment: If you want to set the position of the element to the right in "div", you may try this :
 .toolbar a {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
  }

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `display:flex` with `float` becuase it is against rules - by default floats are ignored in `flex containers`. You should either use floats or flex for your layout, and I hardly recommend `flex`.

I advice for further reading: [flex guid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

To adjust your code replace you styles with:

```
 .toolbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-color: #1976d2;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Nevertheless if you want your code to work with `floats` you will have to remove `align-items` which is `flex` property and remove `display:flex`, that will make your code to work - items will float right.

Comment: relative is not a valid value for `display`, i think you mean `position:relative`?

Comment: You are right, my mistake I meant that floats are ignored in flex container. He should either use float or flex